# How to display data into datagridview using multi thread?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have application where I read/receive data all the time (text) and I need to display this data into datagridview, what is the best way to do that in real time, so the data will be changed all the time.

I thought about multi threading, if this is a good idea can you guide me with link to explain how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Did either of these answers help you at all? Anything else SO might be able to assist you with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to execute a thread in the background to receive data. Then you need to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to marshall calls to the UI thread to update data.

[This link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/williamryan/archive/2004/12/10/23367.aspx) provides some example code you can use as a starting point.